# log4net issue while using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, logging, log4net

I am trying do logging using stored procedure. I created a stored procedure which will insert a row in to the table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insert_log]
(
    @log_date datetime,
    @log_level varchar(10),
    @log_message nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Log] ([log_date], [log_level], [log_message])
    VALUES (@log_date, @log_level, @log_message)
END
```

In my config file

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionStringName  value="AnalyticsLogging" />
    <commandText value="usp_insert_log" />
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
</appender>
```

I am getting the following error

> log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception while writing to database
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'usp_insert_log' expects parameter '@log_date', which was not supplied.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the ConversionPattern and just use

```
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
```

The date conversion is not needed - see [Log4net Conversion patterns](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Layout_PatternLayout.htm)

It converts a datetime to a string - [Iso8601DateFormatter Class](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_DateFormatter_Iso8601DateFormatter.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This started as a comment on Peter's answer (which I agree is the correct answer), but the comment kept growing, so I decided to add a supplemental answer here.

Documentation certainly is tricky to find around this, but in addition, the Raw Layout objects implement `IRawLayout` which is cited [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Layout_IRawLayout.htm) to use raw, unformatted objects instead of a formatted one, which in this case the raw `DateTime` on the `LoggingEvent`.

If you are wanting to provide a formatted `DateTime`, you can use:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss,fff}" />
</layout>
```

Replacing the format with one that you're wanting to use.